# Grails booking calendar

Tags: grails, grails-3.3.0

I'm actually building a clinic app with grails 3.3.0, how can I make a form that shows a calendar for booking appointments, also I need that the calendar days that doesn't have space show a red color

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ This website is more about correcting code that has already been written and which has issues you're seeking help with _ Usually the code is included in the post so that SO contributors can read through it _ Please take a moment to visit the Help Center and specifically the section on 'Asking' for more details >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking